# is R output for lm showing beta or b weight

Tags: r, regression

I searched the questions and have not found a clear answer. I am doing regression in R using the lm function. When the summary is returned, it has regression coefficients, but I can't figure out if these are beta or B weights? In other words, are they standardized or unstandardized coefficients? I'm new to R and usually use SPSS, which label them as standardized/unstandardized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R's lm() function outputs un-standardized coefficients. You can try lm.beta package if you want to extract standardized ones. In its original documentation (in this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lm.beta/lm.beta.pdf)), you can find a simple example about how to use it.

```
model <- lm(Y ~ X)           #fit linear model.
model.beta <- lm.beta(model) #standardize coefficients
```